# No Power For USB 3

Tags: drivers, usb-3

I purchased the Syba USB 3.0 PCI-E USB card as it had an internal connecter for USB 3.0 and my motherboard did not [PCI-E Card](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815124120) BUT it seems that drivers are properly installed[image]

**EDIT**
Why is this device not receiving power?

Comment: is there a question here?

Comment: @Keltari - sorry looks like I hit the submit button before actually asking.  I was wanting to know why the device is not receiving power (meaning the USB ports will not power anything)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question seems like it might be "why doesn't my usb card provide power".

Did you attach the card to the one of the power supply connections?  If the link you provided is for the card you have, then you almost certainly need to do that, if you are expecting your USB port to provide any power and not depend on external power supplies.

[image: Needs Power]

Comment: The 2 ports built into the card work, I am also connecting via 24 pin (the black box in the image) 2 USB ports on the front of my case which do not receive power.  Is that due to the molex cable not being connected to a power supply?

Comment: that is the reason